# CS50 Credit task review

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50

I've got a very interesting case. I've written source code compiled and it was work but when I added my code to course for review got next issues:

```
:) credit.c exists.

:) credit.c compiles.

:( identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX expected "AMEX\n", not "\nAMEX\n"

:( identifies 371449635398431 as AMEX expected "AMEX\n", not "\nAMEX\n"

:( identifies 5555555555554444 as MASTERCARD
    expected "MASTERCARD\n", not "\nMASTERCARD\n"

:) identifies 5105105105105100 as MASTERCARD

:) identifies 4111111111111111 as VISA

:( identifies 4012888888881881 as VISA
    expected "VISA\n", not "\nVISA\n"

:( identifies 1234567890 as INVALID
    expected "INVALID\n", not "\nINVALID\n"

:) identifies 369421438430814 as INVALID

:( identifies 4062901840 as INVALID
    expected exit code 0, not 1

:) identifies 5673598276138003 as INVALID

:( identifies 4111111111111113 as INVALID
    expected exit code 0, not 1

:) rejects a non-numeric input of "foo"

:) rejects a non-numeric input of ""
```

The next part is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    long long card_num;


    // getting card number    
    do
    {
        card_num = get_long("Number: \n");
    }
    while (card_num < 1 || card_num > 9999999999999999);

    for (int i = 0; i < card_num.length(); i++)
    {
        if (card_num[i] == '-')
            printf('foo\n');
            card_num[i] == '';
        else (card_num[i] == ' ')
            printf ('foo\n');
            card_num[i] == '';
    }

    long long temp_num = card_num;

    int count = 0;

    while (temp_num > 0)
    {
        temp_num = temp_num / 10;
        count++;
    }


    // umber volume cheking    
    if (count != 13 && count != 15 && count != 16)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // luna's algorithm checking    
    int sum = 0;
    temp_num = card_num;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        int digit = temp_num % 10;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            digit *= 2;
            if (digit > 9)
            {
                digit -= 9;
            }
        }

        sum += digit;
        temp_num /= 10;
    }

    if (sum % 10 != 0)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 1;
    }    

    // bank info cheking    
    temp_num = card_num;
    while (temp_num > 100)
    {
        temp_num = temp_num / 10;
    }

    int company_id = temp_num;
    if (company_id > 50 && company_id < 56 && count == 16)
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if ((company_id == 34 || company_id == 37) && (count == 15))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if ((company_id / 10 == 4) && (count == 13 || count == 16))
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Please provide the problem detail so that we can help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your problem appears to be faulting on invalid input, and inserting newlines in front of the expected output in many cases.  Show your attempts to diagnose and resolve these; the effects should be quite limited in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! CS50 has their own SE community that you can find [here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/).

Pay close attention to what the errors are telling you. There is an extra carriage return (`\n`) being output somewhere, as indicated by this: `:( identifies 378282246310005 as AMEX expected "AMEX\n", not "\nAMEX\n"`. Notice the difference between what check50 expects (`"AMEX\n"`) and what the program outputs (`"\nAMEX\n"`). Once that is corrected it will eliminate 5 of the errors. Good start.

Review the code to see where it is returning an exit code of 1. That is not required by the spec. Stick to the spec. Sometimes more is not better :).  When that is corrected, it will eliminate the last two errors.

Perhaps these seem like small details that shouldn't affect grading. But if a boss or a customer expects a specification to be followed exactly, these "small details",could translate to real money.